# Storing lots of entries in embedded DB

Tags: database, storage

I have written an application that is used to manage tasks. Very similar to tasks management in MS Outlook. I would like to store data of these tasks in some sort of database, but have no idea where should I start.

This database have to be embedded in my application and should be stored in single file. I was thinking about something similar to Outlooks PST file.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your application is written in but I would look at SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I would rather use something other than RDBMS.I know that MS is using something like OLE Structured Storage and this would be somethig I am looking for.